# Unable to access JSON arrary

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I got json array from backend as below.I could not able to access JSON arrary

```
var res = '[100, 200]';
```

When I try to access by using `alert(res[0]);` I am getting the first character '['. I suppose to get '100'.

Could any one tell what could be the issue?

**UPDATE :-**
It is working fine if the array has number. It is giving an error if the array has alpanumric character.

```
var  res = '[/csv/8_copy 2.csv, /csv/9_copy 2.csv]'; 
alert(JSON.parse(res)[0]);
```

Comment: Um, it's a string, dude. You need to convert it from a JSON string into a JavaScript construction.

Comment: I can not directly change the array value since it is coming from server. Is there any way to append double quote(") for each item?

Comment: Then your server is not sending you JSON. Parse it according to the rules of the format given in the server's specification document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your need to parse the JSON string:

```js
var res = '[100, 200]';

alert(JSON.parse(res)[0]);
```

Comment: Above is working. But I am getting syntax error if the array has alphabetic character. I got error when I tried with var  res = '[/csv/8_copy 2.csv, /csv/9_copy 2.csv]';  alert(JSON.parse(res)[0]);. what could be the issue?

Comment: That is not a proper JSON string because the items in the array are missing quotes. They should be like this: `'["/csv/8_copy 2.csv", "/csv/9_copy 2.csv"]'; `

Comment: i can not directly change the array val since it is coming from server. Can you tell me how to append double quote(") for each item?

Comment: thanks, it is working. the response can be anything like [/csv/8_copy 2.csv, /img/23.png, number, text]. In that case the above reg express wont suite. Can we do it by using comma(,)? Is there any common approach?

Comment: will there be commas in the array items? because you can use the comma as the separator

Comment: I have comma in my response. I tried var  res = '[/csv/8_copy 2.csv, /csv/9_copy 2.csv, text, no]';
str = res.split(",");
console.log(str);
I got the result as  ["[/csv/8_copy 2.csv", " /csv/9_copy 2.csv", " text", " no]"]. can you tell me how to remove first and last square brackets ?

Comment: `var str = res.replace(/[\[\]]/gi,'').split(",");` removes all occurrences of brackets. `var str = str.replace(/^\[(.*)\]$/gi,'$1').split(",");` removes brackets from beginning and end only.

Comment: Getting an error on line var str = str.replace(/^\[(.*)\]$/gi,'$1').split(","); Seems everything is correct. I dont know why it is giving err

Comment: you are missing backslashes on the brackets

Comment: backslash is there. var str = str.replace(/^\[(.*)\]$/gi,'$1').split(",");  this site is removing backslash automatically. How to make the code as put above. I tried with Ctr+K. it is not working

Comment: Thanks Moogs for sharing JSfiddle

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JSON as data, you have to parse it.

```
var res = JSON.parse('[100, 200]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse`.

```
var result = JSON.parse('[100, 200]');
alert(result[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted says that your `var res` is equal to a string (not an array).

This means that the array accessor method you're trying will not work until you parse the string into an array.

You can use JSON.parse() to change the string into an array:

```
var res = '[100, 200]';
var resParsed = JSON.parse(res);
```

Then you can access the elements of the array as you were trying to before:

```
alert(resParsed[0]);
```